# Chrome Extension : URL permission not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-webrequest

We are using chrome webrequest API to intercept and modify headers on request.
I was working fine until Chrome 72, but it's not working anymore. But when I replacing the permission with `"<all_urls>"` that's work.
Also, I tried with another domain, Google, like this example : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest and that not working too.

Did you have any idea about why that not working anymore ?
We will use `"<all_urls>"` for the moment but it's a huge permission that we do not really need.

manifest.json :

```
"permissions": [
 "webRequest",
 "webRequestBlocking",
 "*://*.merchantos.com/*"
 ]
```

background.js

```
  chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    details => ({
      responseHeaders: filter(details.responseHeaders),
    }),
    { urls: ['*://*.merchantos.com/*'] },
    ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
  )
```

**EDIT :**

Problem **solved**. For Chrome 72 you now need to add the host of the request into your permission to be able to edit headers.

manifest.json :

```
"permissions": [
 "webRequest",
 "webRequestBlocking",
 "*://*.merchantos.com/*",
 "*://*.mywebsite.coom/*/,
 ]
```

Comment: See the documentation for webRequest: to modify certain headers you need 'extraHeaders' now.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm , thanks for your answer.
I tried to add this extras headers but that do not change anything :/
```javascript
  chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    details => ({
      responseHeaders: filter(details.responseHeaders),
    }),
    { urls: ['*://*.merchantos.com/*'] },
    ['blocking', 'responseHeaders', 'extraHeaders']
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

With Chrome 72, you need to specify both the target URL that you want to intercept, *and* the website URL from which the request is made in the permissions.

For example: `https://www.mywebsite.com/` makes a request to `https://abc.merchantos.com` which you want to intercept. Thus:

- mywebsite.com is making the request
- abc.merchantos.com is the target, which you would like to intercept
- You have to specify both those URLs in your `manifest.json`:

  ```
  {
      ...
      "permissions": [
          "webRequest", 
          "webRequestBlocking",
          "*://*.mywebsite.com/*", 
          "*://*.merchantos.com/*"
      ],
      ...
  }
  ```